# Css side nav and two horizontal navbars

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a home screen that looks like this, but I cant get it to work mobile and desktop. 
All the nav bars need to be fixed and then the  second one with the games needs to collapse and the side bar under it when on mobile.

any advice would help!
[mobile and desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RnE2.jpg)
here is fiddle my https://jsfiddle.net/jweldon/nrphdafs/

```
/*---------------- NAVBAR  STUFF -------------------*/
body {
    margin-top: 50px;

}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

/* remove outer padding *navbar-lowsecond-navbarer/
    .main .row{
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    /*Remove rounded coners*/

.second-navbar {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 12%;
    position: relative;
}

body > nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.sidebar {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1 > ul > li > a {
    color: black;
}

    #bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1 > ul > li > a:hover {
        background-color: darkgray;
    }
    #bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1 > ul > li > a:active {
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
    }

#games-nav > ul > li > a {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    border-color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#li-scrabble {
    background-color: green;
}

#li-go {
    background-color: orange;
}

#li-chess {
    background-color: blue;
}

#li-mtg {
    background-color: black;
}


nav.sidebar, .main {
    -webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
    transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
}

/* Add gap to nav and right windows.*/
.main {
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

/* .....NavBar: Icon only with coloring/layout.....*/

/*small/medium side display*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    /*Allow main to be next to Nav*/
    .main {
        position: absolute;
        width: calc(100% - 40px); /*keeps 100% minus nav size*/
        margin-left: 40px;
        float: right;
    }

    /*lets nav bar to be showed on mouseover*/
    nav.sidebar:hover + .main {
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    /*Center Brand*/
    nav.sidebar.navbar.sidebar > .container .navbar-brand, .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    /*Center Brand*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-brand, nav.sidebar .navbar-header {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    /*Center Icons*/
    nav.sidebar a {
        padding-right: 13px;
    }

    /*adds border top to first nav box */
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li:first-child {
        border-top: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
    }

    /*adds border to bottom nav boxes*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li {
        border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
    }

    /* Colors/style dropdown box*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    /*allows nav box to use 100% width*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-collapse, nav.sidebar .container-fluid {
        padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
    }

    /*colors dropdown box text */
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #777;
    }

    /*gives sidebar width/height*/
    nav.sidebar {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -160px;
        float: left;
        z-index: 8000;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

        /*give sidebar 100% width;*/
        nav.sidebar li {
            width: 100%;
        }

        /* Move nav to full on mouse over*/
        nav.sidebar:hover {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
    /*for hiden things when navbar hidden*/
    .forAnimate {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

/* .....NavBar: Fully showing nav bar..... */

@media (min-width: 1330px) {
    nav.sidebar.navbar {
        border-radius: 0;
        position: fixed;
    }

    /*Allow main to be next to Nav*/
    .main {
        width: calc(100% - 200px); /*keeps 100% minus nav size*/
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    /*Show all nav*/
    nav.sidebar {
        margin-left: 0px;
        float: left;
    }
        /*Show hidden items on nav*/
        nav.sidebar .forAnimate {
            opacity: 1;
        }
}

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #CCC;
    background-color: transparent;
}

nav:hover .forAnimate {
    opacity: 1;
}

section {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .second-navbar {
        width: 100%;
        top: 0px;
    }

    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        left: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.active {
        position: relative;
        left: 250px;
    }

        #wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
            left: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        }
}


footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

    footer legend {
        color: white;
    }
/*FLAG CSS*/
.flag-language-select {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}


/*CAROUSEL IMAGE*/
img.bg {
    /* Set rules to fill background */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
    #tag-line {
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
    img.bg {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px; /* 50% */
    }
}
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .content {
        padding: 15px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    #menu-bar .panel {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    #menu-bar li a {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #side-navbar {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .content {
        margin-left: 200px;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }

    .container {
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 150px;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
}

#top-nav {
    background-color: white;
}

#logo {
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
}

.navbar-brand > h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#side-navbar {
    margin-top: 118px;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    z-index: 1200;
}


/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

label > input { /* HIDE RADIO */
    visibility: hidden; /* Makes input not-clickable */
    position: absolute; /* Remove input from document flow */
}

    label > input + img { /* IMAGE STYLES */
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
    }

    label > input:checked + img { /* (RADIO CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
        border: 1px solid #00bfff;
    }

.radio-img {
    max-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: An image of the collapsed version would be useful...

Comment: added, I can't have two images so made one with both.